# Test Class: Unable to assert enqueueJob

Tags: code-coverage

The queueable job is enqueued in the finish method of the batch class but I am unable to assert in the test that queueable job got enqueued.

System.enqueueJob was returning null Id in the test then I tried to set a static boolean variable to true before System.enqueueJob line but the boolean variable is returning false in the test class.

```
Batch Class:

@TestVisible static Boolean queueableIsQueued = false;

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

 if(currentWeekday == Setting) {
      queueableIsQueued = true; // setting here to true
      System.debug('@BatchVar:: '+queueableIsQueued);  // returns true
      System.enqueueJob(new SomeClass.acctQueueable());
    }
}

Test Class: 

Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(batch);
Test.stopTest();

System.debug('@testVar::'+BatchClassName.queueableIsQueued); // return false
//This line is executes before the debug in the batch finished method
```

EDIT: Additional Details

Following are the options I tried to do a assert in test class. Seems like the finish method simply isn’t being called until after the (debug in test class) /assertion

```
Option 1:

  public static Id jobId;
  Batch Class:
  {
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

     if(currentWeekday == Setting) {
          jobId = System.enqueueJob(new SomeClass.acctQueueable());
     }
     System.debug('jobId: '+jobId);
    }
  }

  Debug:
  {
    jobId: null
  }


Option 2: 

  Test Class: 
  {
    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(batch);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.debug('list: '+[SELECT Id, JobType, Status, CompletedDate, MethodName FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType = 'Queueable']);
  }

  Debug: 
  {
    list: () // List was empty
  }


Option 3: 

  Batch Class:
  {
    @TestVisible static Boolean queueableIsQueued = false;

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

       if(currentWeekday == Setting) {
            System.enqueueJob(new SomeClass.acctQueueable());
       }

       List<AsyncApexJob> lst = [SELECT Id, JobType, Status, CompletedDate, MethodName FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType = 'Queueable'];
       if(lst.size() > 0) {
          acctMetricsQueueableIsQueued = true;
          System.debug('list: '+lst);
       }
    }
  }

  Test Class:
  {
    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(batch);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.debug('var: '+BatchClass.queueableIsQueued);
  }

  Debug: 
  {
    Var: false
    list: (AsyncApexJob:{Id=7072900000XaKfBAAV,...}
  }

Option 4: 

  Queueable Class:
  {
    public static Boolean queueableIsQueued = false;

    // queueable class constructor
    acctQueueable() {
       queueableIsQueued = true;
       System.debug('Queueable class var:'+queueableIsQueued);
    } 
  }

  Test Class:
  {

    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(batch);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.debug('var: '+QueueableClass.queueableIsQueued);
  }

  Debug: 
  {
    Var: false
    Queueable class var: true
  }

  Option 5:

    Batch Class: 
    {
      @TestVisible static Boolean queueableIsQueued = false;

      global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

         if(currentWeekday == Setting) {
            queueableIsQueued = true; // setting here to true
            System.debug('@BatchVar: '+queueableIsQueued);  // returns true
            System.enqueueJob(new SomeClass.acctQueueable());
         }
      }
    }

  Test Class:
  {
    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(batch);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.debug('var: '+BatchClass.queueableIsQueued);
  }

  Debug:
  {
    var: false
    @BatchVar: true
  }
```

Comment: Presuming that currentWeekday == Setting, it should have worked. Are you sure that the values are correct?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, its working and debug under this if(currentWeekday == Setting) is printing.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to assert the Id of a queueable job which is the equivalent of what you're trying to do with `System.enqueueJob(new SomeClass.acctQueueable())`. From the Apex Developer Guide documentation on [Queueable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm):

> The ID of a queueable Apex job isn’t returned in test context — System.enqueueJob returns null in a running test.

The only way I can think of to accomplish what you're trying to assert is to use the `system limits class` with something like `getLimitQueueableJobs()` both *before* and *after* your batch job executes *during the test context*, then comparing the values that are returned. I'd expect you to see a difference that reflects the job that gets enqueued by the batch class which should reduce the available limit of queueable jobs by 1.